# How to "dereference" variables in keymappings?

Tags: vimscript

I just learned about vimscript. I'm trying to write a small vimscript that'll kinda copy what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316727/automatic-closing-brackets-for-vim) does, but more verbosely and very explicitly. (The first case would case typing a `(` will insert `()`)

```
" make keymappings
for [opener, closer] in {'(': ')'}
  inoremap l:opener <C-r>=InsertPair(opener, closer)<CR>
endfor

" Typing the opener will also insert the closer
function! InsertPair(open, close)
  return a:open . a:close . "\<Left>"
endfunction
```

But I ran into a problem. The `inoremap`s aren't working as planned - they're remapping the literal chars `l` `:` `o` `p` `e` `n` `e` `r` instead of the value of the local variable named opener (`(`).

#### Is dereferencing a variable in a call to map possible in vimscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close! Use the `"=` register again. What that looks like for your question is

```
inoremap <C-r>=opener<CR> <C-r>=InsertPair(opener, closer)<CR><CR>
```

---

If you want to lock in the values of the variable at runtime then you can also do something like this:

```
execute "inoremap " . opener . " <C-r>=InsertPair('" . opener . "', '" . closer . "')<CR>"
```

Comment: You could also use printf (it might be sprintf?) to simplify the string passes to exec (ie use formatting replacements rather than tough to read concatenation)